# Ideas behind Gitik's solution of PCF conjecture

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, large-cardinals, cardinal-arithmetic, pcf-theory

Recently Moti Gitik has refuted Shelah's PCF conjecture (see [Short extenders forcings II](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~gitik/short%20extenders%20forcing%202-mar2013.pdf) ) by proving the following theorem:

**Theorem.** Assuming the consistency of infinitely many strong cardinals, one can force a countable set of successor cardinals $A$ such that $|PCF(A)|=\aleph_1$.

I wonder to know if anyone can explain the main ideas behind Gitik's proof of the above theorem.

Comment: I bet Moti could. :-)

Comment: I asked this question of many people at Oberwolfach.  The answers were the same as Asaf's comment. ;)

Comment: Mohammad, @Todd, Moti has began giving an informal course about his proof, and I'm Live-TeXing the whole thing. When there's something to post, I'll probably post it on my site and/or include an answer here if I can give one. He tried to give some approximate idea today, but I drifted off since he started drawing all these diagrams on cardinal structure and whatnot. But speaking to others, it didn't come across very well, and will probably clarify over the next couple of weeks.

Comment: Good luck with this!  This proof is one that needs to be clarified and assimilated ASAP, because it opens up so many possibilities to answer open questions.

Comment: @Todd: Today was the first lecture, and the crowd was roughly 20 people. Surely if I won't be the one to understand it, clear it up and explain it better, someone much better than me at these things will do it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Dear Asaf, nice to hear this. I will be thankful if you  send me the notes you are taking from his lectures.